# imagettftext with uneven spaces

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 470, $m, $black, $font, "this is testing of all");
?>
```

When I run this function I get the image with uneven spaces.
like this:
this is testin g o fall

[alt text http://fb.prideofhome.com/11111.JPG](http://fb.prideofhome.com/11111.JPG)

Comment: Try `imagefttext()` instead. If that doesn't work better, please show a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a so-called [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) problem. TrueType fonts contain information about the spacing between certain pairs of characters to achieve a natural flow of letters.

From my experience, GD's TrueType function `imagettftext()` often doesn't use the kerning information contained in TrueType fonts, or does not use them well enough.

Try `imagefttext()` first. (notice the `ft` instead of the `ttf`) It makes use of the FreeType library.

If that doesn't improve the result, you may have to resort to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) if your server supports it. But try the Freetype functions first.